# How with help of RegExp in JavaScript delete all similar words?

Tags: javascript, regex

How with help of RegExp in JavaScript delete all similar words?
I have below code and I don't know why it isn't work!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var res = 
"I am Bill. Hello Hello Hello Hello, Aleks!".replace(/\b(\w+)\s+\1{2,}/g, "$1");
console.log(res);
</script>
```

P.S. I need the result: `"I am Bill. Hello, Aleks!"`

Comment: You need to group the spaces and the backreference: `\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use:

```js
var res = 
"I am Bill. Hello Hello Hello Hello, Aleks!".replace(/\b(\w+)\b(?:\s+\1\b)+/g, "$1");
console.log(res);
```

---

[Regex Explanation (demo #2)](https://regex101.com/r/jlSZQX/2)